# Populate a dynamic Table from two arrays

Tags: php, html, arrays, yii, dynamic-tables

The first array contains the headers and the other array contains the data to be populated. I am able to create the headers but I am having issues populating the data according to the headers.

```
$columns =([0]=>firstname, [1]=>lastname, [2]=>class);
```

And the data.

```
$data=(
array[0](['firstname']=>kevin, ['lastname']=>kaburu, ['class']=>1) 
array[1](['firstname']=>kevin, ['lastname']=>kaburu, ['class']=>1)
array[2](['firstname']=>kevin, ['lastname']=>kaburu, ['class']=>1)
array[3](['firstname']=>kevin, ['lastname']=>kaburu, ['class']=>1))
```

**Let me make this more clear**

The thing is that I have two table the first one has columns while the other one has records, with foreign key pointing to the column in which they belong. The columns keep on changing so it is extremely dynamic. I want to populatw this data into a table ...
give me the available options.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I think you should use an id to identify each record

Comment: I am using the name of the column to identify the column

Comment: @KevinKaburu can you please explain that do you want to populate a gridView from array or want to populate something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I managed to sort the issue.... This is my code

Action.php

`

```
$recdata = $sql->showuploadedrecords($evntid);
        $coldata =$sql->showuploadedcols($evntid);
        $colmns = array();
        foreach ($coldata as $ky => $valu) {
            $colname = $valu['column_name'];
            $colmns[] = $colname;
        }


        $records = array();
        $total = count($recdata)/count($colmns);
        for ($i = 1; $i < $total +1; $i++) {
             $one =array();
            foreach ($recdata as $k => $v) {

                if($v['relate_records']==$i){
                   $one[]=$v;

                }

            }
             $records[] = $one;


        }



        $this->render('ViewUploaded', array('colmns' => $colmns,
            'data' => $records));
    }`
```

And on my View:

```
`echo '<tr role="row">';
            foreach ($colmns as $value) {
                echo '<th  class="sorting_asc" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 219px;" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Rendering engine: activate to sort column descending">'. $value . '</th>';   

            }
            echo '</tr>';
            ?>

                    </thead>



            <?php

                       foreach ($data as $key => $v) {
                            echo '<tr>'; 

                          for ($k = 0; $k < count($colmns); $k++) {

                       foreach ($v as $cell) {

                           if($cell['column_name']== $colmns[$k]){

                           echo'<td>'.$cell['item'].'</td>';

                           }
                       }

                       }

                        echo '</tr>'; 


                       }



          ?>







                        </tbody>

                 </table>`
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer this Link:

http://www.yiiplayground.com/index.php?r=UiModule/dataview/gridViewArray

You can create gridview with use of `CArrayDataProvider`.

This link cotain example code which is exactly match with your requirement.

**Without using Yii method:**

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<?php
  foreach($columns  as $s)
  {
     echo "<th>$s</th>";
   }
?>
</tr>
<tbody>
<?php
  foreach($data as $d)
  {
     echo "<tr>";
     foreach($d as $cols)
       echo "<td>".$cols."</td>";// hope all columns are present in second array.
     echo "</tr>";
  }
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I would preffer something that has the foreach and for itaration in my case.

Comment: Yii already have option to create. It's ok. Let me update my answer.

Comment: My colmns are not static neither, meaning I cant pre determine the number of colmns.

Answer (score 1):

insert this after your data declaration:

```
$dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($data, array(
    //CDataProvider options, sort, etc..
));
```

change the render call to include passing the dataProvider to your view:

```
$this->render('view', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
));
```

in view:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    // other CGridView options
)); ?>
```

Comment: I have edited my question now... I like your Idea but i have not yet worked with CgridViews